# Adding NewWindow3 to WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, vb.net

I've been converting a VB.NET application to C#. It's been a smooth operation for the most part.

In VB.NET I'm able to add the NewWindow3 Handle to a WebBrowser control with the following code;

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    WebBrowserCOM.Navigate("about:blank")
    Dim svd As SHDocVw.WebBrowser = DirectCast(WebBrowserCOM.ActiveXInstance, SHDocVw.WebBrowser)
    AddHandler svd.NewWindow3, AddressOf NewWindow3
End Sub

Public Sub NewWindow3(ByRef pDisp As Object, ByRef cancel As Boolean, ByVal flags As Integer, ByVal URLContext As String, ByVal URL As String)
    ...
End Sub
```

I translated it to;

```
public frmAutoStateCertInput() {
    InitializeComponent();
    WebBrowserCOM.Navigate("about:blank");
    SHDocVw.WebBrowser svd = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser)WebBrowserCOM.ActiveXInstance;
    svd.NewWindow3 += NewWindow3();
}

public void NewWindow3(out object ppDisp, out bool Cancel, uint dwFlags, string bstrUrlContext, string bstrUrl) {
    ...
}
```

But when I translate it to C# I get an error;

```
Error   CS0123  No overload for 'NewWindow3' matches delegate 'DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow3EventHandler'
```

What am I supposed to do to fix this issue?

Edit: The error is on the "svd.NewWindow3 += NewWindow3();" line.

Comment: When I changed it, I still got the same error. I used the layout here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/shdocvw.dwebbrowserevents2_newwindow3eventhandler?view=dynamics-usd-3 which is how I got such a different implementation. I also tried a direct convert of the VB.NET sub.

Comment: First two arguments should be ref instead of out to match the event signature. A distinction that doesn't exist in vb.net

Comment: your data type of the flags in vb is integer...but in the C# is an unsigned integer

Comment: That was it. I changed the two out to ref and the int to uint and it worked.